# C# RegEx to match specific strings

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-web-api

I need to match (using regex) strings that can be like this:

required: custodian_{number 1 - 9}_{fieldType either txt or ssn}
optional: _{fieldLength 1-999}

So for example:
custodian_1_ssn_1 is valid
custodian_1_ssn_1_255 is valid

custodian or custodian_ or custodian_1 or custodian_1_ or custodian_1_ssn or custodian_1_ssn_ or custodian_1_ssn_1_ are not valid

Currently I am working with this:

```
(?:custodian|signer)_[1-9]?[0-9]_(?:txt|ssn)_[1-9][0-9]?(_[1-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?
```

as my regex and my api is working to pick up:
custodian_1_txt_1
custodian_1_ssn_1
**custodian_1_txt_1_25**5  <---- not matching the last "5"

any thoughts?

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't be using Regex for this. It would probably be easier and faster to use something like `string.Split('_')` and then iterate over the resulting array, checking for validity and required attributes.

Comment: Your best bet is to play with it in a RegEx tool: https://regex101.com/r/s9ilVe/1

Comment: You say you want to match numbers 1-9 for the first field, but `[1-9]?[0-9]` would match 0-99. Why is the first digit optional, and why is there a second digit at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use pattern:

```
^custodian(?:_[a-z0-9]+)+$
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `custodian` Match literal substring `custodian`.
- `(?:_[a-z0-9]+)+` Non capturing group. Multiple sequence of `_` followed by alphanumerics.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

You can check the correct matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/i6Hi1i/1).

Obviously you can modify the pattern to add substring `signer` in non capturing group as:

`^(?:custodian|signer)(?:_[a-z0-9]+)+$`.

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it works in all cases I tried.  Although, it seems it would works for something out of scope as well IE:
custodian_1_xxx_1_15 where xxx is not an acceptable sub-string.  It's Ok, though, I will document around this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `\d` for numbers not yours and this is my code try it:-

```
(?:custodian|signer)_[1-9]?[0-9]_(?:txt|ssn)_[1-9][0-9]?(_[1-9]?\d*)?
```

I just added a `\d` value to the end of your pattern to match all end digits before another match.

Comment: The end bit matches a string ending in `_` (with no number). You can fix that by getting rid of the `?` after the last `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anchor to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and for the last part make at least the first 1-9 not optional or else it would match and underscore at the end:

[`^(?:custodian|signer)_[1-9]?[0-9]_(?:txt|ssn)_[1-9][0-9]?(_[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hmYECg/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the last digits, this super generic regex will do:

```
(?:.+)_(\d+)
```

If you do need to match the whole string, this worked:

```
^(?:custodian|signer)_\d+_(?:txt|ssn)(?:_\d+)?_(\d+)$
```

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Well it doesn't match the whole string, but it does match some of it. Added anchors.

Comment: Yeah that's better, the last capturing group should be made non capturing though.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness OP's regex captures the last group.

Comment: Uh, apologies, my bad.